# Doing inner join on two spark data frames having same column names giving empty result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've two data frames d1 and d2 having same column names.

```
d1.printSchema()
root
 |-- child: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parent: string (nullable = true)

d2.printSchema()
root
 |-- child: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parent: string (nullable = true)

d1.show()
d2.show()

+--------+---------+
|   child|   parent|
+--------+---------+
|street_1|   city_1|
|street_2|   city_2|
|street_3|   city_1|
|street_4|   city_2|
|  city_2|  state_2|
|  city_1|  state_1|
| state_1|country_1|
| state_2|country_2|
+--------+---------+
```

When I do inner join on both these, it's giving empty result. But when the column names are changed in the second data frame d2, join is working fine. Please help with this.

```
d1.join(d2,d1['parent']==d2['child'],'inner').show()

+-----+------+-----+------+
|child|parent|child|parent|
+-----+------+-----+------+
+-----+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: pls show d1 as well

Comment: both d1 and d2 have the same data